# How count save data per second in ScadaLTS

Tags: scadalts

Create benchmark for the ScadaLTS,
who checks how much data is stored in the database per second.

Create data source

[image]

Copy three times

[image]

And enable every data-source and data point.

And How count save data per second in ScadaLTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using SQL:

```
select 
count(*),
 YEAR(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
        MONTH(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
        DAY(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
        hour(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
        minute(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
        second(from_unixtime(ts/1000))
from pointValues 
where
  YEAR(from_unixtime(ts/1000))  = YEAR(NOW()) and
  MONTH(from_unixtime(ts/1000))  = Month(NOW()) and
  DAY(from_unixtime(ts/1000))  = DAY(NOW())
group by
    YEAR(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
        MONTH(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
        DAY(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
        hour(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
        minute(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
        second(from_unixtime(ts/1000))
Having count(*) >5
order by count(*) DESC
```